# Search for queries into .percolator type

Tags: elasticsearch, indices, elasticsearch-percolate

I have an Elasticsearch v2.4.2 index, I'm filling its .percolator type with a bunch of queries and some special values. query-docs looks like this:

```
"query" : {
      "query_string" : {
        "fields" : [ "title", "meta" ],
        "query" : "notebooks AND clamps"
      },
      "key_id" : 14,
      "owner_id" : 481,
      "priority" : 50,
      "special_id" : 477
    }
```

I'm trying to delete some of these queries from .percolator, specifically those with even "key_id" values.

The problem is that I'm trying to perform a search on the .percolator but I'm not getting the results. for instance, I tried these curl calls:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/percolate_index_d/.percolator/_search?q=key_id:14&pretty'


curl 'localhost:9200/percolate_index_d/.percolator/_search?&pretty' -d '{ query:{filtered:{filter:{term:{"key_id":"14"}}}} }'
```

But I always get this:

```
 {
      "took" : 6,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [ ]
      }
    }
```

I even tried using `query.key_id` but no luck. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, if it's possible to search on .percolator type or if there is some workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above query is not correct at all. Try running it against your index and you'll see that you have syntax errors.

The correct syntax for your query is like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "meta"
          ],
          "query": "notebooks AND clamps"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "key_id": 14
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "owner_id": 481
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "priority": 50
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "special_id": 477
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to search queries with `key_id: 14` like this:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/percolate_index_d/.percolator/_search?q=query.bool.filter.term.key_id:14&pretty'
```

**UPDATE**

The metadata key_id|owner_id|priority|special_id fields of your query are not set in the right place, you need to set them outside of the `query` field, like this_

```
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "fields" : [ "title", "meta" ],
      "query" : "notebooks AND clamps"
    }
  },
  "key_id" : 14,
  "owner_id" : 481,
  "priority" : 50,
  "special_id" : 477
}
```

After doing so, you'll be able to retrieve your queries with

```
curl 'localhost:9200/percolate_index_d/.percolator/_search?q=key_id:14&pretty'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I don't want to filter by key_id|owner_id|priority|special_id. My query above is just a .percolator query-document. I added the values like "key_id" in order to use them when I find a match with "_percolate" API. The query works fine with_percolate but I need to search in the .percolator type (for example) query-docs with key_id < 200

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood your initial need. I thought key_id|owner_id|priority|special_id were also supposed to be term filters of your query, but you're only adding them as metadata fields of your query. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked as expected! Do you know why didn't it work the way it was before doing, "query.key_id=14"?

Comment: Because as I said in my answer, any metadata fields you add need to go outside of the `query` object, hence you cannot query for `query.key_id` if `key_id` is at the top level of your document.